# Android apps with Dojo and geodjango

Tags: android, python, django, dojo

I am trying to make a android apps using Dojo toolkit and GeoDjango. Its a project based on GPS work. Can anyone help in this issue? I want to have the staring steps? I have some source code and SDK installed in my computer. But still confused about the staring. can Anyone help?
How I will make it possible to create the apps. Steps plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to take a look at PhoneGap. I use it to embed JQuery mobile inside a Android application. PhoneGap makes it easy to embed javascript inside an Android application. Just try the PhoneGap tutorial.

Edit: PhoneGap let u use the GPS sensor through javascript